# Running multiple command line after each other linux python

Tags: python, linux, perl, shell

I want to run multiple commands in the same line after the previous is done.

I do the following bellow in a python script:

```
os.system("start_view myView && perl /home/user/Development/count_test.pl -rev 001 -project myproject && /usr/bin/python /home/user/Development/setDoneFlag_Count_Lines.py")
```

First I set a view in clearcase **start_view myview**, then I want to execute a perl program. Problem is it doesn't, it just sets the view (which I need in order for me to execute the perl program) but it never actually starts the perl program, so the question is am I doing anything wrong? It seems like **start_view myView** starts a new shell, so how do I execute a perl script in the newly created shell that the view starts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you show us `start_view`, since we can only guess…

Comment: Have you tried `;` instead of `&&` ? Perhaps the first command returns unsuccessfully.

Comment: If `start_view` is starting a new shell, it may simply not be returning.  Perhaps `start_view` takes an option to allow it to start a process in the shell that it creates.

Comment: If this is like **ClearCase**, `start_view` will have an option (e.g. `-c`) where you can give it a command to run in the shell that has been launched in the view's context; if it exists, move the rest of your command into there.  

Additionally, `&&` short-circuits upon failure (i.e. non-zero status), but `;` does not (i.e. each command runs in succession).  You can also do `||` for reverse short-circuit (i.e. execute only if there's a failure).  For example try: 
`/bin/true && echo TRUE || echo FALSE` 
and 
`/bin/false && echo TRUE || echo FALSE`

Comment: Are you using Rational ClearCase's `startview`?  Maybe you want `setview -c your_commands_here`? [setview doc](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setview.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-66)

Comment: I needed to add the -exec command as you above and that made the trick. Thanks for the help =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general multiple dependent commands should work when invoked from os.system():

```
>>> rv = os.system("ls /dev/null && grep mhawke /etc/passwd")
/dev/null
mhawke:x:1000:1000:mhawke:/home/mhawke:/bin/bash
>>> rv
0
```

But if one command fails (as determined by a non-zero exit status) the following commands are not executed:

```
>>> rv = os.system("ls /phantom && grep mhawke /etc/passwd")
ls: cannot access /phantom: No such file or directory
>>> rv
512
```

So, are you sure that `start_view` returns exit code 0? Are you sure that `start_view` returns at all? - could it be blocked waiting for input. Are you sure that the command isn't actually [`startview myView`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_startview.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-68)?

You could find out by executing this on the command line:

```
$ start_view myView
$ echo $?
```

If it displays `0`, then try the next command in the chain until you find the culprit.